# How to create infinity within a Leslie matrix in R

Tags: r

In the matrix I have to create I want some infinity because I work with an organism that has no lifetime limit. I also know that the survival chance are 50% and that from age 3 the fecundity is always 2 , I have already written :

```
    fecundity = c(0,0,2,2,2)
survival = c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
Ll=survival*fecundity
for(i in 1:4){
  row= c(rep(0,i-1), survival[i],rep(0,5-i))
  Ll=rbind(Ll,row)
}

Nc=runif(5,1,10)

maxxTime=20
allNc = Nc
for (i in 1:maxTime) {
  Nc = Ll %*% Nc
  allNc = cbind(allNc, Nc)
}
```

But the problem is that with this code i don't have  infinity(it stop at 5 values) and i don't know how to do it

Comment: Terminology problem? Translation form a foreign language to English? I'm wondering if you are not asking for "infinity" but rather for censoring? After all, the only thing you can say about the lifetime of an individual who is still alive at time of hte final observations is that you have not yet observed a death.

Comment: Here is what we ask me maybe it will help :  an organism that has no upper limit of lifetime, but from age 3 years onwards, it produces 2 surviving offspring each year, and its probability of survival is 50% in every
year. (This is something like a typical passerine.) How do you deal with the fact that there is no limit for age?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Create a transition matrix that has a transition "tunnel" that allows aging for 2 or 3 intervals depending on how you conceive of the process evolving when translated to a discrete scale of time.  without fecundity for 3 years. You would need to specify whether the 50% survival probability starts immediately at birth of after 3 years. I suspect you could also do it in continuous time with differential equations. You might see explosive growth but that would manifest itself as finite but unbounded growth in simulations.

Comment: Thx I manage to find the answer